# Gerando ID's sequenciais para cada usuário em uma mesma tabela MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Sempre utilizei a própria chave primária como código de identificação padrão para cada registro em uma tabela do banco de dados. A partir do momento em que a tabela passou a ser utilizada por diversos usuários, sendo que cada um possui os seus próprios produtos cadastrados, não será possível mais manter aquela sequência padrão (um a um) para cada usuário, visto que o código mantém a sequência da chave primária. Deste modo, gostaria de verificar uma maneira mais otimizada e prática para a geração de um código sequencial para cada usuário. 
Ao criar uma nova coluna para o código sequencial de cada usuário, pensei nas seguintes possibilidades:

- Ao gravar o produto de cada usuário, verificar o seu código gerado (começando por 1, obviamente) e então armazenar em um campo de parâmetros do usuário o próximo código a ser usado por ele.
- Ou então, ao gravar o produto, buscar o código do último produto gravado na tabela, e então incrementar + 1 para o novo produto. (Não acho uma maneira adequada, pois ao excluir produtos, ele poderia reutilizar código apagados).

O que me recomendam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapaz, eu acho melhor a primeira opção como o amigo @Nicolas Pereira disse antes, já fiz uma aplicação com a sua segunda opção mais foi a pedido do cliente, justamente pra não peder a sequência gerada.

Comment: obrigado pelo suporte!

Answer (score 2):

Você gostaria de criar uma sequencia para cada usuario? Acredito que você poderia fazer a primeira opção. criar uma tabela auxilia com o ID_USER e  o LastCodigo dele e na hora de dar o insert você pesquisa qual foi o LastCodigo e incrimenta +1 para o codigo!

A opção de ele excluir um produto não teria problema com a tabela auxiliar, e seria legal pra vc saber quantos produtos ele tem no total (excluidos ou não)

Comment: obrigado pelo suporte!